# Span and Subspaces Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to get my head around how this. If I have two vector spaces $V$ and $U$ where $U$ is a subset of $V$, if $U$ can be represented by a span of vectors, does that mean $U$ is a subspace of $V$?

For example, let $V=P_ \infty$ and $U=\{ (a)x^3 + (a+2b)x^2 - (b-a)x + (a+3b) \}$. $U$ is clearly a subset of $V$. If $U = \{ (a)x^3 + (a+2b)x^2 - (b-a)x + (a+3b) \}$, does that mean if I write $U = \langle x^3+x^2+x+1,2x^2-x+3\rangle$, does that mean that $U$ is a subspace of $V$?

Comment: Yes: the span of any set of vectors in $V$ is necessarily a subspace of $V$

Comment: @BenGrossmann So because $U$ is a subset of $V$, all vectors in $U$ are in $V$, which means I get from my statement in my question to yours?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in your comment

Comment: @BenGrossmann My question is, if I have $V=P_\infty$ and $U=(a)x^3 + (a+2b)x^2 - (b-a)x + (a+3b)$, since $U$ is a subset of $V$, and I can represent $U$ as a span of vectors $U = \langle x^3+x^2+x+1,2x^2-x+3\rangle$, does that prove that $U$ is a subspace of $V$ without having to use the subspace criterion?

Comment: @BenGrossmann And just to make sure, if I wanted to prove that $P_2$ is a subspace of $P_4$, could I do: $P_2 = \{a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2\} = \langle 1,x,x^2\rangle $, so that means $P_2$ is a subspace of $P_4$ as $P_2$ is a subset of $P_4$ and $P_2$ can be written as a span of vectors?

Comment: Is $P_\infty$ the set of polynomials in the variable $x$ ? You say $U = P_7$ (which is a set) but a line later say $U = ax^3 + (a+2b)x^2- (b-a)x + (a+3b)$ which is a specific polynomial (i.e. not a set). Which is it ? Can you precise what $P_7$ is ?

Comment: @Digitallis $P_ \infty$ is the set of all polynomials up to an infinite degree. I didn't write the question properly. Please check my edit. $U$ is a set of polynomials of that form.

Comment: Pedantic note: in general if $U$ is a vector space which is a subset of a vector space $V$, it need not be a subspace. To be a subspace its operations must align.

Comment: @blargoner So it must be closed under addition and scalar multiplication right?

Comment: @blargoner But if I can write $U$ as a span of vectors then surely it’s automatically a subspace of $V$ as long as $U$ is a subset of $V$.

Comment: @adisnjo The question is *which* addition and scalar multiplication operations? The ones restricted from $V$, or some other operations that we define on $U$? Like I said, this is a pedantic comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $S \subset V$ is such that $U = span(S)$ then this means that $U$ is subspace of $V$.

Indeed $span(S)$ can be defined as the smallest vector subspace of $V$ containing $S$. By its very definition $span(S)$ is a vector subspace.

If you are not familiar with this definition of the span of a set then you most likely know that $span(S)$ is the set of all linear combinations of elements in $S$ which is again a vector subspace (since it contains $0$  and because a sum of linear combinations is a linear combination)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. So if I wanted to prove that $P_7$ is a subspace of $P_\infty$, I could just write $P_7 =$ span $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6,x^7 \}$ to prove this? And for any set like $A =$ span $\{x^2,5x^5-2,7x^{19}-2x^{12} \}$, this is automatically a subspace of $P_{20}$ and $P_\infty$?

Comment: @adisnjo Yessss.

Comment: Okay cheers. This is much easier than using the subspace test.